# Perl: open file but not overwrite existing one but append number

Tags: perl

I wonder if any module exist that can automate file numbering process.
If i try open "foo.bar" and it exists i open "foo_1.bar" without race condition.
What if two apps try open some file. Open fail or they get filehandles with diferent number?
Very thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opens unique file name for writing. Return array ref to IO::File ref and writing name.
If fail return undef. Work with warnings and strict.

```
use Fcntl;
use Errno;
use IO::File;

sub open_unique {

    my $file = shift || '';
    unless ($file =~ /^(.*?)(\.[^\.]+)$/) {
        print "Bad file name: '$file'\n";
        return;
    }
    my $io;
    my $seq  = '';
    my $base = $1;
    my $ext  = $2;
    until (defined ($io = IO::File->new($base.$seq.$ext
                                   ,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL))) {

        last unless $!{EEXIST};
        $seq = '_0' if $seq eq '';
        $seq =~ s/(\d+)/$1 + 1/e;
    }

    return [$io,$base.$seq.$ext] if defined $io;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a canned module to do this off the top of my head, but the basic idea if you want a sequential file name is:

```
use Fcntl;
use Errno;

$seq = "";
until (defined ($fh = sysopen("foo".$seq.".bar", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600))) {
  last if $! != EEXIST;
  $seq eq '' && $seq = '_0';
  $seq =~ s/(\d+)/$1 + 1/e;
}
# if !defined $fh then $! contains the error, otherwise "foo".$seq.".bar" is created
```

Comment: Exactly what i nead :D Very very txh :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/~tjenness/File-Temp-0.22/Temp.pm).

Something like:

```
($fh, $filename) = tempfile('foo_XXXX', SUFFIX => '.bar');
print $fh "Some data\n";
close($fh) or die;
```

Comment: I should add `use File::Temp qw(tempfile);` at the beginning. This method does NOT create sequentially numbered filenames.